# Numpy: Convert values in a 1-D array based upon dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have the following array and dictionary.

```
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
>>> mapping = {'a': 9, 'b': 0}
```

I want to apply a function that converts `np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']` to `np.array([9, 0, 9, 9])` based upon this input dictionary. But I want this operation to be vectorized. Without using a `for loop`, how can I achieve this conversion?

Note that [np.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and [np.apply_over_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html) both won't work, because they require the input array to be 2-D.

**EDIT**: Note that the actual datasets that I'm working with are very large, and the one here is just a simple example.

Comment: "Very large" is a bit vague.  A million?  A billion? Much more than a billion?   Also, roughly how many keys will `mapping` have?

Comment: Have you browsed the numpy or scipy docs to see if there is a solution?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Just a dataset big enough that would barely fit into my RAM. (I'm preparing for the degenerate situation where I would need to prepare for datasets with a billion rows.)

Comment: @wwii: Yes. Otherwise, I wouldn't know of the functions `np.apply_along_axis` nor `np.apply_over_axis`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple ideas.

First, define some sample data:

```
In [36]: data = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'])

In [37]: mapping = {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 5}
```

You can use `numpy.unique` to get the unique elements in `data`, and (more importantly) an array that maps those unique values back to the input array:

```
In [38]: keys, inv = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
```

At this point, `keys[inv]` recreates `data`.  But we want to create the mapped array, so we'll make an array of the *values* in `mapping`, in the same order as the keys returned by `np.unique`:

```
In [39]: vals = np.array([mapping[key] for key in keys])
```

Now we can index `vals` with `inv` to get the desired result:

```
In [40]: result = vals[inv]

In [41]: result
Out[41]: array([9, 0, 9, 9, 5, 0])
```

Another approach, this one fairly straightforward, is to simply loop over the keys in `mapping`, and do a vectorized assignment of the values into a new array:

```
In [42]: result = np.empty(data.size, dtype=int)

In [43]: for key, val in mapping.items():
   ....:     result[data == key] = val
   ....:     

In [44]: result
Out[44]: array([9, 0, 9, 9, 5, 0])
```

Without know more about the actual size of `data` and the number of keys in `mapping`, it is hard to say which method will be more efficient.

Here's a method you probably won't want to use, because the 2-d intermediate array formed by the expression `data.reshape(-1, 1) == keys` will have shape `(len(data), len(mapping))`:

```
In [63]: keys = np.array(mapping.keys())

In [64]: vals = np.array(mapping.values())

In [65]: result = vals[(data.reshape(-1, 1) == keys).nonzero()[1]]

In [66]: result
Out[66]: array([9, 0, 9, 9, 5, 0])
```

Comment: I like your second answer (calling the for loop on `mapping.items()`) the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple call to `map`?

```
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
>>> mapping = {'a': 9, 'b': 0}
>>> map(lambda x: mapping[x], data)
[9, 0, 9, 9]
```

This doesn't use numpy and won't be extremely fast if you array is large, but it's simple and probably not woth worrying about until you run into performance problems.

Comment: Correct, this would be a brisk way to go. But like you acknowledged, this solution only works if the dataset is small, and I'm working with large datasets.

Comment: Pandas [has a `map`function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html). Maybe you could try that.